# Can we dynamically load routes in NextJS based on a API request result?

Tags: next.js

I have an app built on `create react app` which loads the route information (Allowed list of routes for the logged in user) from the server and generate the routes based on that. For example,

1. The user logs in
2. The app makes a get request to fetch the routes array
3. The app goes through the fetched results and returns a route:

```js
routes.map((route) => <Route path={route} />)
```

My question is, can we do something similar in NextJS?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could use [router.push](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush).

```js
api.login()
  .then(() => router.push('/some-route')
```

NextJS even has this [example project](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/using-router) that could help you

Now, to expand further, if you mean to say that your API will be returning the URI that you have to redirect to, then you just need to read from it:

```js
api.login()
  .then(responseBody => router.push(responseBody.uri)
```